# Store a custom parameter in Postgresql 9.2.4 configuration file

Tags: sql, postgresql, configuration-files, postgresql-9.2

How to store a custom parameter in Postgresql 9.2.4 configuration file ? viz postgresql.conf

Comment: What about editing the file?

Comment: I tried editing but postgres only allows me to store parameters which it identifies. If I add custom parameters then I am not able to restart my postgres server. Also I tried using customized options [https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-custom.html] but it doesn't work in 9.2.4 version

Comment: You did see "*Custom options have two-part names*" [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-custom.html), did you?

Comment: I have seen it, but I didn't understand. How does a key value pair i.e. setting and its value looks  if I implement two-part names . Can you please give an example.